# MYSQL group by column if group member doesn't have another column value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a structure like below:

```
LOGIN    OPEN_TIME              CMD
1        2018-09-17 17:13:06    6
1        2018-09-17 17:11:06    5
1        2018-09-17 17:15:06    4
2        2018-09-17 17:13:06    6
3        2018-09-17 17:12:06    6
3        2018-09-17 17:23:06    6
3        2018-09-17 17:43:06    4
2        2018-09-17 17:23:06    6
```

I want to get the table result like below

```
2        2018-09-17 17:13:06    6
```

It means give me the records group by login when the records belong to that group only have CMD 6 if the group members besides CMD 6 have CMD 0,1,2,3,4,5 doesn't show them.

You can see the fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81506f/1

Comment: For next time, maybe see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery that finds all the logins that have `CMD != 6`, then filter them out.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE login NOT IN (
    SELECT login
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE cmd != 6)
```

or

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.login = t2.login AND t2.cmd != 6
WHERE t2.login IS NULL
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oktf98r5QtX8r1FK64692P/0)

Comment: That works perfectly now I want to get those logins who had cmd 6 and after that they had other cmd's but no cmd 6 anymore. So cmd 6 before other cmd's and no cmd 6 after other cmd's.

Comment: This is starting to sound like homework, and the whole point is for you to figure out how to do things like this on your own. That's how you learn to program.'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table
    WHERE cmd <> 6
)
```